# WinUI 3 DropDownButton's FlyOut width 100%

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have a simple dropdown here:

```
<DropDownButton Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Select" Margin="0,7,0,0">
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="List of items" />
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="SelectFlyout" Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedLeft">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

I managed to set DropDownButton itself's width to 100% of its container (Grid, which is half screen wide), but couldn't manage to do the same with its Flyout. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

1. Name your `DropDownButton` and also subscribe to `MenuFlyout`'s `Opened` event:

```xml
<DropDownButton
    x:Name="DropDownButtonControl"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,7,0,0"
    Width="1000"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Select">
    <TextBlock
        FontSize="14"
        Text="List of items" />
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout
            x:Name="SelectFlyout"
            Opened="SelectFlyout_Opened"
            Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedLeft">
            <MenuFlyoutItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Text="Item 1" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Text="Item 2" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Text="Item 3" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

2. Then in code-behind set the `Width` of each element:

```cs
private void SelectFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper
        .GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot(this.XamlRoot)
        .FirstOrDefault() is not { } popup ||
        popup.Child is not MenuFlyoutPresenter menuFlyoutPresenter)
    {
        return;
    }

    double targetWidth = this.DropDownButtonControl.ActualWidth;
    menuFlyoutPresenter.MaxWidth = targetWidth;

    foreach (MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem in menuFlyoutPresenter
        .FindDescendants()
        .OfType<MenuFlyoutItem>())
    {
        menuFlyoutItem.MinWidth = targetWidth;
        menuFlyoutItem.MaxWidth = targetWidth;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

To use the `FindDescendants` extension method, you need to install the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions) NuGet package.

Comment: I tried binding like MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=DropDownButtonControl, Path=ActualWidth}" but it doesn't work. any ideas why?

Comment: AFAIK, binding doesn't work from `Flyout`/`Popup`.